# Everyplay crashes on iOS7 when attempting to start recording

Tags: cocos2d-x, ios7, everyplay

When testing our app on a device running on iOS7, the app crashes whenever [[[Everyplay sharedInstance] capture] startRecording] is called.

We are unable to trace WHAT is crashing, i.e. pinpointing a specific library or class, as the debugger spits out an error with a memory address in assembly.

Comment: There are two possibilities.  A) It crashes on other devices, in which case you should ensure that exception breakpoints are enabled.  B) It doesn't crash on other devices, in which case you can't ask this question here since it is about confidential software (The Apple Developer Forum is the only place).

Comment: ios 7 is under NDA ... no answer here, try the apple dev forums  or the everyplay devs directly

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about something under NDA.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The version 1.5 of the Everyplay SDK has work arounds for iOS 7 beta 2 to the crash bugs we've seen so far. Please give it a try: https://github.com/everyplay/everyplay-ios-sdk